# Populate Drop Down 2 based on Drop Down 1 with Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js

Here is my first dropdown (Drop Down 1) code-

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select name="t_col" v-model="dbColumn" class="form-control" v-on:change="columnChange(dbColumn)">
        <option value="source_country" selected>Source Country</option>
        <option value="destination_country">Destination Country</option>
        <option value="import_log">Import Log</option>
        <option value="shipment_date">Shipment Date</option>
        <option value="commodity_code">Commodity Code</option>
        <option value="customs_code">Customs Code</option>
        <option value="supply_quantity">Supply Quantity</option>
        <option value="net_mass">Net Mass</option>
        <option value="gross_mass">Gross Mass</option>
        <option value="value">Value</option>
        <option value="total_taxes">Total Taxes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my second dropdown (Drop Down 2)-

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select name="t_rel" class="form-control t_rel" v-model="filter">
        <option value="equal" selected>=</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my `app.js` code-

```
new Vue({
    el:'#query_wrapper',
    data:{
        rows: [
            {}
        ],
        filter: [
            { 
                column:"source_country", 
                value:[{ value:"equal", text:"="}]
            },
            { 
                column:"destination_country", 
                value:[{ value:"equal", text:"="}]
            },
            { 
                column:"import_log", 
                value:[{ value:"equal", text:"="}]
            }
        ],
        dbColumn:{}
    },
    methods:{
        addRow: function () {
            try {
                this.rows.push({});
            } catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        removeRow: function (row) {
            this.rows.$remove(row);
        },
        columnChange: function (dbColumn) {
            console.log(dbColumn);
        }
    }
});
```

Now I need to populate the second drop down (Drop Down 2) based on the selection of first dropdown  (Drop Down 1). So I thought I should populate it from data object. So I took a json object name `filter` and here I've defined some values as `column` and `value`. Now I need to populate the second drop down with value from the `value` array from `filter` object by cross matching `dbColumn` and `column`. Hope I've made you guys understand my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using v-for:

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectbox1">
    <option value="food">Food</option>
    <option value="drink">Drink</option>
    <option value="desert">Desert</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="selectbox2">
    <option v-for="option in setOptions" v-bind:value="option.val">{{option.text}}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <span>selected: {{selectbox1}} {{selectbox2}}</span>
</div>


new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    selectbox1: undefined,
    selectbox2: undefined,
  },
  computed: {
    setOptions: function(){
      if (this.selectbox1 === 'food'){
         var options = [{val: 'pizza', text: 'Pizza'},
                        {val: 'lasagna', text: 'Lasagna'},
                        {val: 'salad', text: 'Salad'}]
      } else if (this.selectbox1 === 'drink'){
         var options = [{val: 'beer', text: 'Beer'},
                        {val: 'wine', text: 'Wine'},
                        {val: 'coke', text: 'Coke'},
                        {val: 'water', text: 'Water'}]
      } else if (this.selectbox1 === 'desert'){
         var options = [{val: 'tiramisu', text: 'Tiramisu'},
                        {val: 'icecream', text: 'Icecream'},
                        {val: 'espresso', text: 'Espresso'}]
      }
      return options
    }
  }
})
```

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erik127/p656ke3v/2/

Answer (score 1):

Define a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) which returns the content of whatever you want in Drop Down 2 -- based on the value of `dbColumn` (the bound data of Drop Down 1).  Then let data binding to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off editing the `<options>` inside the HTML.

```
<select v-model="mySelection">
  <option v-for="o in options" :value="o.value">{{o.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/p8qtuvtd/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your code is not working. Just go to the `jsfiddle` link.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ca5kx6 just go to the link. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: This is actually weird, what does the console says?