# Handle Cascading Drop Downs Within a Grid in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am running into an issue where I have a product that can have multiple categories.  Additionally, these categories have subcategories.  I understand how to handle creating a v-for to manage the categories and to create the select elements to allow the user to choose one.  What I am stuck on is how can I pass the result of the user choosing a category to refresh the subcategory select.    Here is a link to the [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/puyehazela/1/edit?html,js,output) I created to show what I am referring to, which hopefully make it easier to explain what I am trying to do.

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div  id="app">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Subcategory</th>
      <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="addCategory">Add Category</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="category in currentProduct.categories">
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="category.categoryName">
          <option v-for="category in categories">{{ category.categoryName }}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="category.subcategoryName">
          <option v-for="subcategory in subcategories">{{ subcategory.subcategoryName }}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js

```
var app = new Vue({        
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            currentProduct: {
                categories: [
                  { categoryName: "",
                    subcatgoryName: ""
                  }
                ],

            },
            categories: [
                { categoryName: "Category 1" },
                { categoryName: "Category 2" }
            ],
            subcategories: [
                { "Category 1": [{ subcategoryName: "Subcategory 1" }, { subcategoryName: "Subcategory 2" }, { subcategoryName: "Subcategory 3" }] },
                { "Category 2": [{ subcategoryName: "Subcategory 4" }, { subcategoryName: "Subcategory 5" }, { subcategoryName: "Subcategory 6" }] }
            ]
        },
      methods: {
        addCategory: function () {
          this.currentProduct.categories.push({
            categoryName: "",
            subcategoryName: ""
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146676/392102

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using

```
          <option v-for="subcategory in subcategories[category.categoryName]">{{ subcategory.subcategoryName }}</option>
```